# Legendre's symbol negative sign

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a=-2$ in the legendre symbol $\left(\frac ap\right)$, can we take out the negative sign so that the symbol can be written as $$-\left(\frac 2p\right)?$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275005/can-the-jacobi-symbol-be-defined-for-negative-numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\newcommand\leg[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}$general, we can't. What is true is that the Legendre-symbol is *multiplicative*:
$$\leg{ab}p=\leg ap\leg bp.$$
If $a=2$ and $b=-1$, $\leg{-2}p=\leg{-1}p\leg 2p$, but this is not necessarily equal to $-\leg 2p$. As you can see, it depends on the quadratic character of $-1$ modulo $p$.
Recall that
$$\leg{-1}p=\begin{cases}-1&\text{if }p\equiv3\pmod4\\1&\text{if }p\equiv1\pmod4\end{cases}$$
$$\leg2p=\begin{cases}-1&\text{if }p\equiv3,5\pmod8\\1&\text{if }p\equiv1,7\pmod8.\end{cases}$$